# Lorentz invariance of scalars in scalar field theory

Tags: special-relativity, classical-field-theory

To develop classical field theory the following model is considered:

A cubic lattice of particles in which each particle is attached to its 4 closest neighbours by a spring that obeys Hooke's law.

In the continuum limit, the equation for a field specifying a scalar value at each point in spacetime, is obtained via the least action principle. The scalar value associated to any point is equal to the displacement of the particle that would have been at that point if there had been no disturbance in the system, away from that point.

It seems strange to me that one can claim that this scalar value could be Lorentz invariant if in this model the scalar value is the magnitude of a spatial distance. Since spatial distances are not Lorentz invariant.

Am I taking this model too literal?

I would appreciate some intuition!

Comment: https://www.reed.edu/physics/courses/Physics411/html/page2/files/Lecture.16.pdf I believe that equation 16.7 says that the value of the scalar is defined using spatial separation. I understand that it has no direction so I specified that it represents the magnitude of the separation.

Comment: https://www.tcm.phy.cam.ac.uk/~bds10/tp3/introduction.pdf the procedure is very much standard and I've seen it in many lectures, the behaviour of classical fields is derived from it and wherever I look people develop this model and then just began to claim that the scalar field should be Lorentz invariant when it is defined in terms of non-Lorentz invariant spatial separation. Perhaps the answer is just that this model does not consider a real spatial separation but a pseudo-separation that IS a Lorentz invariant and we're not considering a field of physical infinitesimal harmonic oscillators.